azure function node.js - The binding type(s) 'eventHubTrigger, sql, queue' were not found in the configured extension bundle
On azure function in node.js I get this error:
**2024-10-17T07:35:24Z [Error]** The 'delivery-result-handler' function is in error: The binding type(s) 'eventHubTrigger, sql, queue' were not found in the configured extension bundle. Please ensure the type is correct and the correct version of extension bundle is configured. 
**2024-10-17T07:35:24Z [Error]** The 'message-receiver' function is in error: The binding type(s) 'queueTrigger, sql, queue' were not found in the configured extension bundle. Please ensure the type is correct and the correct version of extension bundle is configured. 
**2024-10-17T07:35:24Z [Error]** The 'message-sender' function is in error: The binding type(s) 'queueTrigger' were not found in the configured extension bundle. Please ensure the type is correct and the correct version of extension bundle is configured. 
**2024-10-17T07:35:24Z [Error]** The 'monitoring-channel-queue-trigger' function is in error: The binding type(s) 'queueTrigger' were not found in the configured extension bundle. Please ensure the type is correct and the correct version of extension bundle is configured. 
**2024-10-17T07:35:24Z [Error]** The 'pending-handler' function is in error: The binding type(s) 'sql, queue' were not found in the configured extension bundle. Please ensure the type is correct and the correct version of extension bundle is configured.

It is a log from log stream on cloud.
I haven't seen this problem before, there were no changes to the bindings but suddenly I recorded the problem above despite it working fine. I have checked other posts and they suggest to change version to the latest -4, but it already is as you can see in the files below.
When I run the service locally using azurite on windows laptop, the service also works much faster and fetches documents from queue instantly, and on the cloud it sometimes requires restarts to fetch awaiting documents.
Later I got a connected issue.
2024-10-18T11:25:37Z   [Verbose]   Handling WorkerErrorEvent for runtime:node, workerId:node. Failed with: System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Grpc.GrpcWorkerChannel.PendingItem.OnTimeout() in /_/src/WebJobs.Script.Grpc/Channel/GrpcWorkerChannel.cs:line 1774
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Grpc.GrpcWorkerChannel.StartWorkerProcessAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/WebJobs.Script.Grpc/Channel/GrpcWorkerChannel.cs:line 378
2024-10-18T11:25:37Z   [Verbose]   Attempting to dispose webhost or jobhost channel for workerId: 'b3a7b112-c469-452a-9396-3d6030345e93', runtime: 'node'
2024-10-18T11:25:37Z   [Verbose]   Did not find WebHost or JobHost channel to dispose for workerId: 'b3a7b112-c469-452a-9396-3d6030345e93', runtime: 'node'
2024-10-18T11:25:37Z   [Verbose]   Skipping worker channel restart for errored worker runtime: 'node', current runtime: 'node', isWebHostChannel: 'False', isJobHostChannel: 'False'
2024-10-18T11:25:37Z   [Information]   0 functions found (Custom)
2024-10-18T11:25:37Z   [Information]   0 functions loaded
2024-10-18T11:25:37Z   [Verbose]   FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME value: 'node'
2024-10-18T11:25:37Z   [Verbose]   Adding Function descriptor provider for language node.
2024-10-18T11:25:37Z   [Verbose]   Creating function descriptors.
2024-10-18T11:25:37Z   [Verbose]   Function descriptors created.
2024-10-18T11:25:37Z   [Verbose]   Placeholder mode is enabled: False
2024-10-18T11:25:37Z   [Verbose]   RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcher received no functions
2024-10-18T11:25:37Z   [Information]   Generating 0 job function(s)
2024-10-18T11:25:37Z   [Warning]   No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
2024-10-18T11:25:37Z   [Information]   Executing StatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 200
2024-10-18T11:25:42Z   [Verbose]   Debug file watch initialized.
2024-10-18T11:25:42Z   [Verbose]   Diagnostic file watch initialized.
2024-10-18T11:25:51Z   [Verbose]   [HostMonitor] Host process CPU stats (PID 7208): History=(7,3,0,0,0), AvgCpuLoad=2, MaxCpuLoad=7
2024-10-18T11:25:51Z   [Verbose]   [HostMonitor] Host process CPU stats (PID 6336): History=(0,0,0,0,0), AvgCpuLoad=0, MaxCpuLoad=0
2024-10-18T11:25:51Z   [Verbose]   [HostMonitor] Host process CPU stats (PID 5284): History=(0,0,0,0,0), AvgCpuLoad=0, MaxCpuLoad=0
2024-10-18T11:25:51Z   [Verbose]   [HostMonitor] Host aggregate CPU load 2
2024-10-18T11:26:04Z   [Verbose]   [HostMonitor] Host process CPU stats (PID 7208): History=(0,0,0,0,0), AvgCpuLoad=0, MaxCpuLoad=0
2024-10-18T11:26:04Z   [Verbose]   [HostMonitor] Host process CPU stats (PID 6336): History=(0,0,0,0,0), AvgCpuLoad=0, MaxCpuLoad=0
2024-10-18T11:26:04Z   [Verbose]   [HostMonitor] Host process CPU stats (PID 5284): History=(0,0,0,0,0), AvgCpuLoad=0, MaxCpuLoad=0
2024-10-18T11:26:04Z   [Verbose]   [HostMonitor] Host aggregate CPU load 0
2024-10-18T11:26:04Z   [Information]   Executing StatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 200
2024-10-18T11:26:07Z   [Verbose]   Initiating background SyncTriggers operation
2024-10-18T11:26:07Z   [Information]   Loading functions metadata
2024-10-18T11:26:07Z   [Verbose]   Preventing any new worker processes from starting during shutdown.
2024-10-18T11:28:07Z   [Verbose]   Handling WorkerErrorEvent for runtime:node, workerId:node. Failed with: System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Grpc.GrpcWorkerChannel.PendingItem.OnTimeout() in /_/src/WebJobs.Script.Grpc/Channel/GrpcWorkerChannel.cs:line 1774
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Grpc.GrpcWorkerChannel.StartWorkerProcessAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/WebJobs.Script.Grpc/Channel/GrpcWorkerChannel.cs:line 378
2024-10-18T11:28:07Z   [Information]   0 functions loaded
2024-10-18T11:28:07Z   [Verbose]   Attempting to dispose webhost or jobhost channel for workerId: 'a29066a1-c6a5-4788-86f5-e9a27003118d', runtime: 'node'
2024-10-18T11:28:07Z   [Verbose]   Did not find WebHost or JobHost channel to dispose for workerId: 'a29066a1-c6a5-4788-86f5-e9a27003118d', runtime: 'node'
2024-10-18T11:28:07Z   [Verbose]   Skipping worker channel restart for errored worker runtime: 'node', current runtime: 'node', isWebHostChannel: 'False', isJobHostChannel: 'False'
2024-10-18T11:28:08Z   [Verbose]   Hosting stopping
2024-10-18T11:28:08Z   [Verbose]   Stopping file watchers.
2024-10-18T11:28:08Z   [Verbose]   Waiting for RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcher to shutdown

delivery-result-handler function for example has bindings declared as below:
const channelStateChangeQueue = output.storageQueue({
  queueName: "out-channel-state-queue",
  connection: "StorageConnectionString",
});

const deliveryResultMessageQueue = output.storageQueue({
  queueName: OUT_DELIVERY_RESULTS_QUEUE_NAME,
  connection: "StorageConnectionString",
});

const sqlChannelStateOutput = output.sql({
  commandText: "channel_state",
  connectionStringSetting: "DatabaseConnectionString",
});

const sqlChannelStateLogOutput = output.sql({
  commandText: "channel_state_log",
  connectionStringSetting: "DatabaseConnectionString",
});

const sqlPendingDeliveriesOutput = output.sql({
  commandText: "dbo.delivery_job_pending",
  connectionStringSetting: "DatabaseConnectionString",
});

const sqlLogDeliveryResultOutput = output.sql({
  commandText: "dbo.delivery_log",
  connectionStringSetting: "DatabaseConnectionString",
});

app.eventHub("delivery-result-handler", {
  connection: "EventHubReadConnectionString",
  eventHubName: "EventHubName",
  cardinality: "many",
  extraOutputs: [
    sqlLogDeliveryResultOutput,
    sqlPendingDeliveriesOutput,
    sqlChannelStateOutput,
    sqlChannelStateLogOutput,
    deliveryResultMessageQueue,
    channelStateChangeQueue,
  ],
  handler: async (messages, context) => ...

package.json
{
  "name": "delivery-gw",
  "version": "1.0.4",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "node --test src/tests/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/event-hubs": "^5.11.2",
    "@azure/functions": "^4.0.0",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.16.0",
    "@azure/storage-queue": "^12.16.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "azure-storage": "^2.10.7",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "jwks-rsa": "^3.1.0",
    "mssql": "^10.0.2",
    "sinon": "^17.0.1",
    "uuid-by-string": "4.0.0"
  },
  "main": "src/functions/*.js"
}

host.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "concurrency": {
    "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true,
    "snapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "batchSize": 6,
      "newBatchThreshold": 0
    }
  }
}

I have restarted, stopped, sent the same test cases when I found the error, but I can't recreate it. It just popped up and... fixed itself?

Are you able to run locally without issues ?


On the cloud it sometimes requires restarts to fetch awaiting documents.

Its because, you might be using Consumption function app which goes to sleep mode after being idle for a certain time around 10min. You can consider upgrading to App service plan which comes with Always on functionality or Premium function app plan.
I have the main value as src/{index.js,functions/*.js} in package.json file.
{
  "name": "79101600",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "main": "src/{index.js,functions/*.js}"
}

Add the Connection strings like DatabaseConnectionString, StorageConnectionString in App settings of function app before deploying.
Verify the package version and update if they are old.
